# Mixed Endianness

Tags: assembly, mips, endianness

My computer appears to store ints in bigendian order. For example 0xFF440022 is 4 282 646 562. However it stores string data in little endian order? Ie. hello world is something like
lleh o wo rld . Why is this? Is this machine considered big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: Saying that the computer system "stores string data in little endian order" has no meaning, because strings don't have a "big end" or a "little end" since there is no placewise significance of bytes. Strings are just sequences of one-byte values, and bytes are never so far as I know stored backwards individually...

Comment: How are you seeing this data?  It sounds to me like your debugger is pulling tricks on you.

Comment: XSPIM stores .asciiz "\n Result" like this: "eR_lf tlus" where lf is the line feed. Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single byte (char) doesn't have endian-ness.  A string is simply stored left-to-right with the left most character at the lowest address.

Comment: On a x86 computer, XSPIM stores .asciiz "\n Result" like this: "eR_lf tlus" where lf is the line feed. Why is this?

Comment: It doesn't.  The flaw is that you are reading 32-bit integers instead of bytes.